# stop the file upload in multer if the user validation fails

Tags: node.js, express, multer

The file uploading is done by multer by using this code, but how to stop the file upload when the user validation fails. where to write the user validation part in this code

```
router.post('/profilePicture',
 multer({dest: './uploads/',
rename: function (fieldname, filename,req,res) {
      return image = req.body.userId+'-'+dateTime+'-'+randomId();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file,req,res) {
        if(file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png') {
          imageUploadDone = false;
          return false;
        }
        //console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file,req,res) {
      //console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
      if(file.mimetype == 'image/jpg')
        extn  = '.jpg';
      if(file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg')
        extn  = '.jpeg';
      if(file.mimetype == 'image/png')
        extn  = '.png';
      imageUploadDone=true; 
    }
}),function(req, res) { 
      upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(imageUploadDone==true){
      //console.log(image);
      var userInfo = {'userId':req.body.userId,'newImage':address+image+extn,'path':'./uploads/'};
          db.profilePicture(userInfo,function(result){
            if(result.message == 'image path added'){
              res.json({'success':'1','result':{'message':'Profile Picture Updated','imageUrl':address+image+extn},'error':'No Error'});
            }
          });
    }
    if(imageUploadDone == false){
    res.json({'success':'0','result':{},'error':'file format is not supported'});
  }
  });
});
```

i try to validate the user on the events like onFileUploadStart and onFileUploadComplete. if user is not valid still the file gets uploaded to the path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the body before uploading file in multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663527/how-to-get-the-body-before-uploading-file-in-multer)

Answer (score 7):

This is now possible in 1.0.0.

If you want to abort the upload:

```
multer({
      fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
         if (path.extname(file.originalname) !== '.pdf') {
                 return cb(new Error('Only pdfs are allowed'))
          }

         cb(null, true)
       }
 })
```

If you want to skip any files that is not pdf:

```
multer({
      fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
          if (path.extname(file.originalname) !== '.pdf') {
                  return cb(null, false)
       }

      cb(null, true)
      }
 })
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to validate depending on the file extension which can be easily changed by the user. Multer provides `mimetype` for each file which can not be faked. So, I think using `file.mimetype` would be more secure.

Comment: According to the [Typescript definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c1bf1945c4eab17ac4fee075ad9885223961242f/types/multer/index.d.ts#L30-L31), `file.mimetype` refers to the value of the `Content-Type` header, which can also be spoofed.  Some file types may be identified from their [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). Unfortunately, you cannot verify this at the `fileFilter` stage because it runs before the file transfer actually takes place, so only the metadata is available.

Answer (score 3):

**What you can do to validate the format of file : In your app.js put this code**

```
const multer = require('multer');

/* defined storage and filename */
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname);
  }
});

/* defined filter */
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("File format should be PNG,JPG,JPEG"), false); // if validation failed then generate error
  }
};

app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single("image")
);
```

Now whenever your file is uploaded by key 'image' its format will be checked, if not satisfied then error will be generated.

Hope this will help to someone!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do file related validation, i.e mime type or file size, you can do this with fileFilter.

```
multer({
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
       // file validation...
    }
});
```

The only problem with the above method is that you cannot do validations against the body of the request. `req.body` is empty inside the `fileFilter` callback as explained in this Github [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/299).

There is a workaround for this, which is described in this Github [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/146). This is not an optimal solution IMO because it forces the client to ensure validation.

Another option is to let the file be saved and then do your validation checks on `req.body`, if the request is invalid you can use something like [del](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del) or [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) to delete the persisted file from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of addressing this problem.

```
const path = require('path');
multer({
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {

var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg/;
var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

if (mimetype && extname) {
  return cb(null, true);
}
cb("Error: File upload only supports the following filetypes - " + filetypes);
}

});
```

There is a further discussion about this issue on following link.
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/114