# verify request body before uploading file using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm currently working on an API with nodejs. I want the user to upload files along with other required details. but the problem is that multer uploads the file before i am able to verify the required details that the user passes. Is there a way to upload the file only after the req.body values have been verified?

My current code:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("gallery_item_image"), function (req, res, next) {
    Branch
        .findById({ _id: req.body.branch_id })
        .exec()
        .then((doc) => {
            if(!doc || req.body.branch_id.length < 24) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: "Invalid Branch ID",
                })
            }
            galleryItem = new GalleryItem({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                branch_id: req.body.branch_id,
                caption: req.body.caption,
                description: req.body.description,
                absoluteImagePath: req.file.path,
                imagePath: "some.url"
            })
            return galleryItem.save()
        })
        .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                res.status(201).json({
                    message: "Gallery item successfully added to the database",
                    galleryItem: {
                        _id: response._id, 
                        branch_id: response.branch_id, 
                        imagePath: response.imagePath.replace("\\", "/"),
                        caption: response.caption, 
                        description: response.description, 
                        date: response.date,
                        absoluteImagePath: response.absoluteImagePath,
                        meta: {
                            type: "GET", 
                            url: "some.url",
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: error
            })
        })
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the body before uploading file in multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663527/how-to-get-the-body-before-uploading-file-in-multer)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what author asked but if you're looking to verify request with JWT or something similar you can add authentication data in request headers like

```
Authorization: TOKEN_OR_ANY_AUTHETICATION_DATA
```

You will be able to access headers without having access to body so it might solve your problem. so that you can use this data in your middleware. or any function you call before uploading files

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a middleware before the multer actual middleware. Like the following code:

```
const validator = function(req, res, next) {
    // Do some validation and verification here
    if(okay)
       return next();
    else
       return res.status(400).send({message: 'Invalid Arguments(For Example!)'})
}
```

And use this function as a middleware before upload.single just like this:

```
router.post("/", validator, upload.single("gallery_item_image"), function (req, res, next) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

I hope it helps you.